# rake aborted! syntax error, unexpected tLSHFT

Tags: ruby, rake

I use mountain lion, i install ruby-1.9.3-p125. And i use `rake new_post['test']`, 
the terminal return the information:

```
rake aborted!
/Users/John/octopress/Rakefile:10: syntax error, unexpected tLSHFT, expecting $end
<<<<<<< HEAD
  ^
```

how could i solve the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you had a conflict during your last git merge, you should see things like `======` and `>>>>>>>>` in the vicinity as well. Fix the merge conflict and try again.